# Question: I am trying to check if the mat-cards are being viewed by the user, if yes then set the variable seen="Yes"

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Question: I have multiple mat-cards and I am trying to check if the mat-cards are seen by the user, if yes then set the variable `seen="Yes"`

I have a parent component which calls child component to display each mat-card on the screen. So, I just need to check if each of these mat-cards are displayed and is viewed. If yes then set the variable `seen="Yes"`.

Parent Component:

```
<app-item
    *ngFor="let document of documents"
  >
  </app-item>
```

Child Component (app-item):

```
<mat-card class="Cards">
...
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Can you share little bit more code. How parent component display child component. When you consider the mat-card as viewed?. It just based on showing the card to user or user need to do some interaction?

Comment: It is based on showing the card to the user. Through "app-item" tag parent component is calling the child component.

Comment: What you mean by calling? can you share the template. Need to see how your template look like to give suggestion